# How to close all query windows in DBeaver?

Tags: dbeaver

DBeaver retains all results & sql editor windows when the program is closed.

The indicator showing tab overflow is easy to overlook (see pic). A user can accumulate an absurd number of tabs if they aren't paying attention & actively closing tabs after each session. I don't see an obvious way to do it and it's impractical to close them one by one.

How can I close all query windows in DBeaver?

I mean 'close' as in save nothing and close the query window completely.

[image]

Comment: Just a small comment to say that on recent versions of DBeaver, the "General > Editors > Database Editor" settings have moved up to simply "Database Editor".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can right-click on any tab then choose "Close All":

[image: gif]

In order to automatically close database object editors when exiting the application, you can uncheck this option: "Reopen database editors after restart":

[image: options]

Note that this will only close database editors (tables, schemas...) and it won't affect text editors. There's currently (DBeaver 5.1.2) no option to automatically close text editors when exiting the application. The feature request is tracked on [this issue](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/2803).